# Javascript regex search ArrayList for specific word and print words before/after

Tags: javascript, regex, azure, search-suggestion

sorry if this question is already answered but I didn't anything which matches my case.

Currently I am trying to build a search suggestion function with Azure Cognitive Search. This is working pretty fine. But now I try to build something like this:

[image: search suggestion]

The suggestion should show the matching pattern, which is entered in the searchbar with a couple of words before and after. Also shown in the picture.

I tried to build a array which splits the complete content in single words and searches for the pattern. But this seems very ugly to me because I don't know how to reverse the array and get the words before and after. And compile this to a fitting string.

```
          $.ajax({
            url: "https://" + azSearchInstance + ".search.windows.net/indexes/" + azSearchIndex + "/docs?api-version=" + azApiVersion + "&search=" + text + '&$top=' + azSearchResults + '&api-key=' + azApiKey,
            method: 'GET'
          }).done(function (data) {
            // display results
            currentSuggestion2 = data[0];
            add(data);
            for(let i in data.value) {
              var content = data.value[i].content;
              var contentArray = content.split(' ');

              for(let word in contentArray) {
                if(contentArray[word] === text) {
                  console.log(contentArray[word]);
                }
              }
            }
            var render = Mustache.render(template, data);
            $(".search-suggest").html(render)
          });
```

My second try was to use the indexOf() function but it results in the same problem because it only returns a number on which position the matching pattern is located.

```
          $.ajax({
            url: "https://" + azSearchInstance + ".search.windows.net/indexes/" + azSearchIndex + "/docs?api-version=" + azApiVersion + "&search=" + text + '&$top=' + azSearchResults + '&api-key=' + azApiKey,
            method: 'GET'
          }).done(function (data) {
            // display results
            currentSuggestion2 = data[0];
            add(data);
            for(let i in data.value) {
              var content = data.value[i].content;

              console.log(content.indexOf(text));
            }
            var render = Mustache.render(template, data);
            $(".search-suggest").html(render)
          });
```

I am searching for a regular expression which searches for the pattern and prints like 4-5 words before and after the pattern. Does anyone of you has an idea?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

OjunbamO

Comment: You could create a regular expression, that contains groups for the 4-5 words before/after. Then you could search with that regex and finally manipulate the string to show the result you want. But pay attention, that could quickly become slow with complex regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

## `/(([a-z]+[^a-z]+)|([^a-z]+[a-z]+)){0,4}test(([a-z]+[^a-z]+)|([^a-z]+[a-z]+)){0,4}/i`

The first `{0,4}` means up to `4` words before the search term (`'test'`).  The second means up to `4` words after the search term.

It could have been written `{4}` (exactly `4`) but then that wouldn't work when the search term is the first word.  Since there'd be `0` words before it.

Most of the complication owes to the fact that your test case needs to match the `test` inside `{{testHelper}}`, along with the preceding and following words.

```js
const searchTerm = 'test';
const strings = [
  'Hello World! And so, whenever you test-drive a new theme, make sure that you are buckled in.',
  'It is going to be a bumpy ride. In the below example there is a {{testHelper}} defined as an illustration.  This is for illustrative purposes.',
  'Some users have encountered the issue of duplicating the URL as TestName.github.io/Test for illegitamate uses.',
  'You do not have to, but if you want, you can click the Test connection button to make sure everything works as intended.',
];
const regExpString = String.raw`(([a-z]+[^a-z]+)|([^a-z]+[a-z]+)){0,4}${searchTerm}(([a-z]+[^a-z]+)|([^a-z]+[a-z]+)){0,4}`;
const regExp = new RegExp(regExpString, 'i');

strings.forEach(string => {
  const match = string.match(regExp)?.[0];
  console.log(match);
});
```